# Why is my onload function not working?

Tags: javascript, header, onload

Here is the index file to my web application located in the host_name directory.

```
<?php

  include 'b2.php'; 

  session::start();

  if(session::is_active())
    {
    include 'b2e.htm';
    }
  else
    {
    include 'b1e.htm';
    }
?>
```

I call

```
public static function reload()
    {
    $uri = 'http://';
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/host_name');
    }
```

to reload the page b2e.htm after a use logs in.

This works.

However, the onload functions are not called in my .js file - here.  There is only one .js file included in both b2e.htm and b1e.htm.

```
window.onload=n;
function n()
  {
  var a;
  if(a=document.getElementById('f0d'))
    {
    a.onclick=i0;
    document.getElementById('f1e').onclick=i1;
    }
  else
    {
    document.getElementById('f2a').onclick=i2;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="#eeeeee"; 
    }
  }
```

basically the statements in the else should execute but the are not.

Comment: Where do you have `i0`, `i1` and `i2` functions defined? Any console errors?

Comment: updated question - only one .js file

Comment: Any console errors? The only issue I see is that those functions are not defined. You'll need to post more code. Aside from the missing functions, the `onload` should work.

Comment: It would if you send the URL or replicate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

A header() call will not initiate the onload function.